# read text file and replace a word in it

Tags: file, tcl

> for example, consider a file "abc.txt" has following content
>
> {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/name.inp"}
>
> {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/result.rst"}
>
> {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/abaqusresult.odb"}

So I want a script which will read this .txt file rearch for "*.rst" and replace with given name for example "badapple.rst"

or I will input "result.rst" search for it and replace it with "badapple.rst" keeping remaining all same and copy all other lines to new file

**and I cannot change syntax of the text file it should exactly write
 {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/badapple.rst"}**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace a string in a file using tcl /expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394788/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-file-using-tcl-expect)

Comment: @RakeshNair Not quite, since that's tangled up in [tag:expect] as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace one string with another in a file, *especially where you are changing the length of the string,* you are going to find it easiest if you load the whole file into memory, perform the change there, then write it back out again.

```
set filename "abc.txt"

# Read in the file
set f [open $filename]
set content [read $f]
close $f

# Alter what is on $content here; !!READ BELOW!!

# Write out the file; assumes we've got the newlines in the content already
set f [open $filename "w"]
puts -nonewline $f $content
close $f
```

So what about that missing piece in the middle? Well, it depends on exactly what change you are trying to make. The details matter *a lot* here. However, if we are wanting to swap out `result.rst` for `badapple.rst` then that's pretty easy with `string map` (which replaces exact strings with other exact strings):

```
set content [string map {"result.rst" "badapple.rst"} $content]
```

Swapping every `*.rst` is a little trickier, as we need to define what `*` really matches here. I'm guessing that it doesn't include directory separators or double quotes! Given that, `regsub -all` is a more appropriate tool.

```
regsub -all {[^\\/""]+\.rst} $content "badapple.rst" content
```

Omitting the `-all` would make it just replace the first matching instance.

The regular expression is:

- `[^\\/""]` — match any character that is *not* (`^`) a backslash, forward-slash or double-quote, with some things doubled for various reasons including quoting and readability
- `+` — one or more of the preceding piece (i.e., one or more non-bad characters)
- `\.` — a full stop (requires a backslash because `.` is a RE metacharacter)
- `rst` — three literal letter characters

If you're writing your own REs, ***always*** put it in `{`braces`}`.

Comment: thank you , really appreciate it